# Storyboard UITable(View?) with Sprite Kit

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uikit, sprite-kit

I just created a tiny little game with sprite kit. Works flawless!

Now I wanted to add a simple menu button (SKLabelNode*) which presents a UITable(View?).
To design the tableViewCells I created a UIViewController in the storyboard and added a UITable.

[image: Storyboard]

Now I need to display this table from my SKSzene. How do I achieve this?
And if that's possible, how do I call methods of my SKScene by touching a tableViewCell?

This displays the tableView but without content...

```
-(void)showTableShop{
TableViewController *table = [[TableViewController alloc]init];
[self.view addSubview:table.view];
}
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Do you understand how the delegate and data source for a table view work?  (Assuming you're using ARC, you should make `table` a strong property of the class that creates it.  Otherwise, you're likely to get memory problems when someone interacts with its view.  Even better would be to create a container view controller if you're going to use another controller's view.)

Comment: I suggest you to interact with your `TableViewController` from `SKScene`'s `ViewController`, instead of `SKScene` directly.

Comment: I understand part of it :)
I managed to create a table with content from an array of it's viewController. But I don't know how to populate it with information of my SpriteKit nodes. Do I need to pass NodeArrays to a custom Init method? Or are there better ways to do so?

**This is how I create the table in my SKScene:
    -(void)showTableShop{
      _table = [[TableViewController alloc]init];
      [self.view addSubview:_table.view];
    }**

Comment: I tried to create a table with prototype cells but the cells stay empty. How do I switch to the uiViewController from my skScene?